# Scraping values from a request response

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Unfortunately i can provide only the output of the request and not the full code since it contains quite private infos, basically when printing the request as text file i get a json one, something like that:

```
{"paymentResource":{"paymentToken":"PAYID-MEJ------","intent":"authorize","redirectUrl":"https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow?nolegacy=1\u0026token=EC-5JS-----2S","authenticateUrl":null}}
```

How can i scrape that Paypal url? tried by doing this but it didn't worked (ppstep2 is the name of the request):

```
content = ppstep2.json()
pp = content["redirectUrl"]
```

I only get this error while doing it:

```
pp = content["redirectUrl"]
KeyError: 'redirectUrl'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable **content** is a dictionary.

To get the value for "redirectUrl" you can do this:

```
pp = content['paymentResource']['redirectUrl']
```

The key error was caused by not including ['paymentResource']

I would recommend reviewing python dictionaries and the .get() method as well.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dictionary%20get#dict.get

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `print(json.dumps(content, indent=4))` before you try to access it and look at the output. You might spot why then.

`redirectUrl` isn't part of `content`. It's in the `content['paymentResource']` dictionary in that response content.

using `content['paymentResource']['redirectUrl']` should work.

Edit: If you want to try and get a value without ending up with an exception, try using .get():

```py
# This will result in a KeyError as you experienced:
pp = content["redirectUrl"]
# This will instead set pp to None if 'redirectUrl' doesn't exist as a Key
pp = content.get("redirectUrl", None)
```